# XML file or database, which is best approach to fetch data

Tags: xml, database

I have run a job and pre-populated the `SQL` Stored Procedure result into an `XML` file. FROM the *UI* result are get directly from the `XML` file instead of getting it from SQL Stored Procedure.

Is it advisable to do so and if yes which one performs the better?

Comment: improve form and english.

Comment: "Is it advisable to do so" — Depends. "From the UI" is too vague to understand what you are doing.

Comment: "which one performs the better?" — Try benchmarking it.